# Calculus double integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem.

Consider a "cylinder" with base bounded by the polar curve $r(\theta)=1+\delta\sin(n\theta)$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\delta>0$ is sufficiently small. Find an approximation for the vertical portion of the cylinder (to error up to second order $\delta$).

I computed the arclength of the base which is needed for the surface area. which is $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(1+\frac{dr}{d\theta})}$ but the expression cannot be integrated nicely.

Comment: The arc length formula should be $\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{r^2+(dr/d\theta)^2}\,d\theta$. Did you try expanding both $r(\theta)$ and $dr/d\theta$ in powers of $\delta$? If you keep only the linear part of the integrand, your integral will be exact up to order $\delta^2$..

Comment: Oh right sorry, I had wrote wrong in the question. The terms under the square root is $(1+\delta\sin(n\theta))^2+(\delta n\cos(n\theta))^2$. what do you mean only keep the linear part of the integrand?

Comment: I mean you can expand the integrand as a Taylor series in powers of $\delta$: $\sqrt{r^2+(dr/d\theta)^2}=1+\delta\sin n\theta +O(\delta^2)$. It follows that your integral is, up to quadratic terms in $\delta$, equal to $\int_0^{2\pi}(1+\delta\sin n\theta)\,d\theta=2\pi$. What that means is that by taking the length of the curve equal the length of the circle, your error is really small for small $\delta$ (of the order of its square).